# Probability distribution of $Z = F(X)$ if that of $X$ is known

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability distribution function:

$F(x) = \begin{cases}
  1 - ae^{-x/5} : x \ge 0 \\
  0              : x < 0
\end{cases}
$

Let $ Z = F(X)$, find the probability distribution function of $Z$.

My attempt: $F(z) = P(Z<z) = P(F(X) <z) = P(X <F^{-1}(z)) = F(F^{-1}(z)) = \begin{cases}
z : z \ge 0 \\
0 : z < 0
\end{cases}
$

Is my answer correct and rigorous enough?

Comment: $F$ doesn't have an inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the continuous distribution of the random variable $X$, the distribution of $F(X)$ will always be the same. This is known as the probability integral transform, also called the inverse transform sampling.

In your final step, the correct conclusion should be

$$P(F(X)\le z)=\begin{cases}0 &,\text{ if }z\le0\\z&,\text{ if }0<z<1\\1&,\text{ if }z\ge1\end{cases}$$

So we see that $F(X)$ has the Uniform distribution over $(0,1)$.

You should denote the distribution function of $Z$ by something like $F_Z(\cdot)$ since you already use $F$ to denote the CDF of $X$. One thing you could also add while deriving the distribution function of $F(X)$ is that the inverse of $F$ exists as $F$ is strictly increasing and continuous.